# How to setup google analytics for testing purpose for localhost?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to setup analytics for localhost and for some reason it doesn't work, I saw in console that something is sent to google but when I open analytics page there is nothing. Also, I have tried to replace tracing id with tracking id for production and still nothing.

Also, what can be interesting, what I currently have on analytics is wordpress pages and now I'm trying to put analytics in angular app which is running from wordpress. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference in setting up analytics for an "in production" site and setting it up for a localhost, just create a tracking ID and embed the JavaScript. Why are you thinking it doesn't work?

Comment: Because nothing is refreshed on analytics. Maybe they need some time to refresh data. :/

Comment: It does take time, check the "real time" data, it may take a minute, but if you have an active session it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Set Cookiedomain to "none" ([as per GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#localhost)).

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'cookieDomain': 'none'
});
```

Comment: Ok I set like that and also in code trying to send with this statement:
ga('send', 'pageview', {
                    'page': '/page',
                    'title': 'page'
                });
And i don't see any update on analytics page.